# Обновление иконки exe не срабатывает

Tags: c++

Программа выполняется без ошибок, но иконка не обновляется. Пробовал и перезагружать компьютер, и очищать кэш иконок - иконка не меняется.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

HGLOBAL hResLoad;   // handle to loaded resource
HMODULE hExe;       // handle to existing .EXE file
HRSRC hRes;         // handle/ptr. to res. info. in hExe
HANDLE hUpdateRes;  // update resource handle
LPVOID lpResLock;   // pointer to resource data
BOOL result;

int main() {
    hExe = LoadLibrary(TEXT("calc.exe"));
    if(hExe == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error loading executable\n");
        return -1 ;
    }

    int res_id = 0;

    for (;;res_id++)
    {
        hRes = FindResource(hExe, MAKEINTRESOURCE(res_id),RT_ICON);
        if (hRes == NULL)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

    }

    hResLoad = LoadResource(hExe, hRes);
    if (hResLoad == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not load resource\n");
        return -1 ;
    }

    lpResLock = LockResource(hResLoad);
    if (lpResLock == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not lock resource\n");
        return -1 ;
    }

    hUpdateRes = BeginUpdateResource(TEXT("test.exe"), FALSE);
    if (hUpdateRes == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open update resource handler\n");
        return -1 ;
    }

    result = UpdateResource(hUpdateRes,RT_ICON,MAKEINTRESOURCE(res_id),MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),lpResLock,SizeofResource(hExe, hRes)); 

    if (result == FALSE)
    {
        printf("Could not begin update resource\n");
        return -1 ;
    }

    if (!EndUpdateResource(hUpdateRes, FALSE))
    {
        printf("Could not end update resoruce\n");
        return -1 ;
    }

    if (!FreeLibrary(hExe))
    {
        printf("Could not free resources\n");
        return -1 ;
    }

    printf("Successfully changed icon!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Кто знает почему такое может быть?

Comment: Я всё-таки ставлю на то, что иконка закеширована. Что, если переименоваать экзешник?

Comment: а вам надо просто установить иконку на экзешник? или в рантайме ее менять?

Comment: Переименовал, иконки всё также нет.

Comment: В рантайме менять.

Comment: ¿Как вы проверяете обновление иконки?

Comment: Смотрю через проводник

Comment: Смотрите лучше через редактор ресурсов.